# Chrome Extension with Typescript, to use @types/chrome, or chrome-types

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension

I want to use TypeScript to develop a Chrome Extension.

The Chrome Extension tutorial [guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/development-basics/#types) says to use the [**chrome-types** package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types) :

> If you are developing using a code editor such as VSCode or Atom, you
> can use the npm package [chrome-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types) to take advantage of
> auto-completion for the [Chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/). This npm package is updated
> automatically when the Chromium source code changes.

However other examples like [this one](https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-chrome-extension-react-typescript/) and [this one](https://betterprogramming.pub/creating-chrome-extensions-with-typescript-914873467b65) and [this one](https://github.com/chibat/chrome-extension-typescript-starter/blob/master/package.json) say to use [**@types/chrome** package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chrome)

Is there a difference between the two packages? Can I use either package?

I think **chrome-types** is updated automatically when the Chromium source code changes whereas the latter is maintained (manually?) in the "DefinitelyTyped" [repository here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/chrome).

Are there other differences?

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm -- if you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[chrome-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types) strong points:

- it's the official package,
- it's auto-generated from Chromium's source code, hence:

  - it's correct
  - it's up to date with the latest changes in the extension API.

Weak points:

- it lacks some rare hand-crafted declarations e.g. the object returned by `chrome.runtime.getManifest()`.